# Pointer is increment to NULL till end of string as below code but while if check its prove to be wrong why?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strdup

Hi pointer is increment to NULL to the end of string as bellow code but while if check its prove to be wrong why?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *p="Hello,"; // after comma NULL is implicit here
    char *q;
    q=strchr(p,',');  // copyied all char from , till null
    printf("%s\n",q); // good its print , 
    char *temp=strdup(q); // temp contain all string of q
    printf("%s\n",temp); // , good
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
        *temp++='\0'; // overwriting , with NULL and increment pointer which now point to NULL
        printf("%s\n",temp); // blank because it is NULL
        if(temp==NULL) // bad why this is not true since pointer temp is pointing to NULL?
        {
            printf("its null\n");  // why i am not getting this
        }
    }
```

Comment: In `if(temp==NULL)` you did not change the pointer, you changed what it is pointing to. Please do not confuse a `NULL` pointer with the `nul` character `'\0'`. In any case in `*temp++='\0';` it does not matter *what* value you set it to, since you increment the pointer, which now points to the `'\0'` that already terminates the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks i got your point i need to check *temp==NULL instead of temp==NULL

Comment: @user3588044 As Weather Vane stated, `NULL` should be used only for pointers.  You should check `*temp == '\0'`, not `*temp == NULL`.

Comment: Please do not increment `temp` unless you have saved a copy of the pointer returned by `strdup`, which calls `malloc`, because you will not be able to `free` the pointer later.

Comment: oh yes thanks copied :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you could increase a pointer and get it to be `NULL` would be if you loop enough so the pointer address wraps and become zero. Or if you subtract the pointer from itself so the result becomes zero.

A valid pointer will otherwise not become a null pointer by simple pointer arithmetic. It might point out of bounds, but it will not become `NULL`.

What happens here is that `temp` is the one-character string `","`. This is the same as an array containing the two characters `','` and `'\0'`. What happens when you do `*temp++ = '\0'` is that you modify the string to become the two characters `'\0'` followed by `'\0'` (you replace the ocmma with the string terminator). After the operation `temp` points to the second `'\0'`. The variable `temp` is itself not a null pointer, but it points to the null character (which is something completely different).

In other words what you possibly want might be something like this:

```
*temp++ = '\0';
if (*temp == '\0') { ... }
```

---

It might be easier to understand if we look at it a little more "graphically".

When you create the duplicate string

```
temp = strdup(q);
```

you will have something like this

```
----+-----+------+----
... | ',' | '\0' | ...
----+-----+------+----
    ^
    |
    +------+
    | temp |
    +------+
```

I.e. the variable `temp` points to a memory location which happens to be the "string" containing a single comma.

When you do `*temp++ = '\0'` what first happens is that you replace the comma that `temp` points to, then increases the pointer, which means it will look like this instead:

```
----+------+------+----
... | '\0' | '\0' | ...
----+------+------+----
           ^
           |
           +------+
           | temp |
           +------+
```

Comment: Wow thats really good i got your point  thanks a lot for your time :-)